# rollback when occured Exception manually

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

in updateUser method: If an exception occurs when calling one of the macro services (like : updateUserContact,updateAccountContact), the updateUser operation must be rollback.

How do I perform a transaction operation to create, update and delete manually in Java?

In the creation method, when an event exception occurs, I delete the related records.

But I do not know what to do in the update and delete.

if invoke userContactStub.grpcUpdate has Exception , i must rollback userAcount.

Does anyone have any suggestions about the rollback transaction in the update ?

I use jpa, grpc(To connect micro services),springBoot.
each micro service has a datasource.

```
//updateUser
AdminUser adminUser = findById();
adminUser.setFirstName(adminUserModel.getFirstName());
adminUser.setLastName(adminUserModel.getLastName());
adminUser.setPassword(PasswordEncoderGenerator.generate(adminUserModel.getPassword()));
adminUser.setUsername(adminUserModel.getUsername());
adminUser.setDateOfBirth(CalendarTools.getDateFromCustomDate(adminUserModel.getDateOfBirth()));
adminUser.setGender(etcItemService.findByIdAndCheckEntity(adminUserModel.getGender_id(), GenderEnum.class,null,true));

adminUser = adminUserRepository.save(adminUser);

//update userAcount For Admin
//call grpcUpdate
this.userAcountStub.grpcUpdate(createRequestModel);


//update UserContact For Admin
//call grpcUpdate
this.userContactStub.grpcUpdate(createRequestModel);


adminUserModel.setId(adminUser.getId());
return adminUserModel;
```

Comment: read about @Transactional and CascadeType.ALL

Comment: can you share some code snippet? What library you are using for persisting in DB ? Spring transactions should automatically rollback, you just have to handle the Exception. @Transaction is needed only when more than 1 DB call is part of single Transaction.

Answer (score 0):

What framework are you using? Are u using JPA?
Assume you are using JPA, you don't have to worry about it. JPA shell pretty much guarantee your data integrity if exception occurred (usually it rollback manually).
However I am not sure about how to rollback a database translation if one of the micoservice you called has thrown an exception.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using JPa (hibernate?), you can simply add `@Transactional` annotation for rollback on top of create , update methods etc. İt handles this job and solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
try(Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL,dbUser,dbPassword);){
conn.setAutoCommit(false);


// perform operations such as insert, update, delete here
// ..

// if everything is OK, commit the transaction
conn.commit();

} catch(SQLException e) {
// in case of exception, rollback the transaction
conn.rollback();
}
```